# How can I find all selfies taken on my iPhone when on my computer?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, photos, metadata

Since iOS 9, the iPhone has had a default album called Selfies that gathers all the selfies you've taken on the device (i.e. all the photos taken with the front-facing camera) in one place. This makes it easy to browse through and manage your selfies on the device itself, but I want to be able to do so after uploading the photos to my computer (such as via [iCloud Photos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) or by manually copying the images in Windows Explorer).

Is this possible? Is there any sort of metadata in the copied photo that indicates that an image was taken with the front-facing camera, or is this information completely stripped once the image is outside of the device itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to the [Google Photos Apps](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-photos/id962194608?mt=8%20%E2%80%9COpen%20Google%20Photos%20in%20the%20iOS%20App%20Store%E2%80%9D). I use this app, and it's so good because all the photos are automatically classified. And you will have a selfie Album that will gather all your selfies ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a question about searching for files in Windows, which is off-topic for this site. That said, Windows does support [searching for EXIF metadata natively](https://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/), which is where the front- vs. rear-facing camera information is stored, so I expect you can use that to your advantage.

If anyone is reaching this page from a search, and is using a Mac: you can easily achieve this by selecting “Selfies” under the “Media Types” album in the Photos app.